# mdx calculated member not returning breakdown measures on rows

Tags: mdx

Please I used a calculated member function to get prev member, but the measures returned are not slicing by attribute 'days' for the calculated column , please any hint (The query I am using is below)

```
WITH
MEMBER [MEASURES].[VALUE1] AS
(
  [Measures].[Sales Amount],
  [Due Date].[Month Number Of Year].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(28)
)

SELECT
{[Measures].[Sales Amount],[MEASURES].[VALUE1]} ON 0,
(
TAIL(
  DESCENDANTS([Due Date].[Month Number Of Year].[Month Number Of Year].MEMBERS)
   ,1),
    [Due Date].[Day Number Of Month].[Day Number Of Month]
) ON  1
FROM 
[AdventureWorksDW2012]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand how you are using `TAIL` and `DESCENDANTS` so I've amended that part of your script.

Here is an example against `AdvWrks` using the `Lag` function that works ok:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [MEASURES].[VALUE1] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Sales Amount]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(28)
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Sales Amount]
   ,[MEASURES].[VALUE1]
  } ON 0
 ,
    Descendants
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2007]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date]
    )
  ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Thanks , but I was able to resolve the issue, the hierarchy [Due Date].[Day Number Of Month].[Day Number Of Month], That I was using was not associated to the years and months  due to collection of key columns, so another had to be  created and not used as part of the hierarchy

Comment: @iftry maybe you want to add an answer with valid `mdx` as I'm still trying to understand this `DESCENDANTS([Due Date].[Month Number Of Year].[Month Number Of Year].MEMBERS)`